# SQL AVG in a subquery - results in "Subquery returned more than 1 value.."

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, subquery

The results from searches I've found have been largely different from what I'm trying to do. I'm pretty sure I'm over thinking things again. Any help or pointers would be appreciated. I'm using mssql and sql server 2012

I have a table that has 3 columns - document_id, member_id and rating. I would like to average the ratings for all of the matching document_id's in the table.

[image]

Here's the whole procedure - but I'll focus on the dirty part after the block:

```
select      @title = title,
            @description = document.[description],
            @authors = authors,
            @create_date = case when create_date is null then null else convert(varchar(10),create_date, 101) end,
            @revision_date = case when revision_date is null then null else convert(varchar(10),revision_date, 101) end,
            @file_format_id = document.file_format_id,
            @document_category_id = document.document_category_id,
            @size = [size],
            @document_key = document_key,
            @visibility = document.visibility,
            @upload_member_id = upload_member_id,
            @calculated_rating = case when document_category.allow_member_ratings = 1 then (select avg(convert(decimal,rating)) from document_rating where [document].document_id = document_rating.document_id) else null end,
            @member_rating = case when (document_category.allow_member_ratings = 1) then (select convert(decimal,rating) from document_rating where [document].document_id = document_rating.document_id) else null end
from club.dbo.document
    inner join club.dbo.document_category
        on (document.document_category_id = document_category.document_category_id)
        inner join club.dbo.file_format
    on (document.file_format_id = file_format.file_format_id)
where document_id = @document_id
  and document_category.club_id = @club_id
```

The part that's giving me the error is the subquery for the @calculated_rating output parameter.

```
@calculated_rating = case when document_category.allow_member_ratings = 1 
then (select avg(convert(decimal,rating)) 
from document_rating 
where [document].document_id = document_rating.document_id) 
else null end,
```

The above results in "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <," If a document_id has more than 1 rating entry, the proc bombs. What's happening obviously is the sum of all the ratings for a particular document_id is not being added/averaged.

So - I tried something like this:

```
@calculated_rating = case when document_category.allow_member_ratings = 1 then 
(SELECT AVG(convert(decimal,document_rating.rating)) 
FROM( SELECT SUM(document_rating.rating) rating 
FROM document_rating 
WHERE [document].document_id = document_rating.document_id 
GROUP BY document_rating.document_id) else null end,
```

There's a syntax error in there because I made a mess - but should I be using an alias here? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

**Resolved**

problem wasn't with the average - but with the member rating. Needed to add an additional restriction to the where statement.

```
@member_rating = case when (document_category.allow_member_ratings = 1) then (select convert(decimal,rating) from document_rating where @member_id = document_rating.member_id and [document].document_id = document_rating.document_id) else null end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not `@avg_rating`.  It is `@member_rating`.  This subquery is:

```
        @member_rating = case when (document_category.allow_member_ratings = 1)
                              then (select convert(decimal,rating)
                                    from document_rating
                                    where [document].document_id = document_rating.document_id
                                   )
                              else null end
```

This could return more than one value.  You probably want an `avg()` in this subquery too.

Your `@avg_rating` query is fine.  It is an aggregation query that returns one row, because there is an `avg()` in the `select` statement and no `group by` clause.  It will return one row and one value, which is what the subquery should be doing.

Comment: A second set of eyes is really helpful sometimes. Thanks for pointing this out, it was an error in the sub query. I needed to add an additional restriction in the "where" statement and add an additional parameter to the procedure. Edited my question. Resolved. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use the subqueries, as you have the same condition 3 times, but instead use Left outer join document_rating on document.document_id = document_rating.document_id
This means you get all the rows of the previous query and the ratings, with just null where there is no rating
Then Group by document_id (rating)

This should improve the performance too.